# GA4 Track Different Views for Internal/External Traffic

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I want to set up a filter to distinguish between internal and external traffic. I still need to be able to track metrics on both of these and not just exclude internal traffic all together.

My GA4 is up and running correctly collecting all data, I implemented the internal traffic filter but that strips away all of the internal traffic so I cannot see/report on it via the 'traffic_type' variable.

Is there a built in function in GA4 already or would I need to add some parameter via GTM to identify the traffic?

Answer (score -1):

From an [article by EasyReporting.io](https://easyreporting.io/how-to-filter-internal-traffic-in-google-analytics-4/#7-step-5-track-both-internal-and-external-traffic-), it appears you can leverage the "+ Add Comparison" feature and look for your filter names. I would test this but all my setups don't leverage internal traffic filtering.